# Audjustable + UISlider, not playing seekToTime when UISlider changes

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avfoundation, audio-streaming

I'm using Audjustable class to play Mp3s from my webservice. It's a great class to use, I recommended.

But I got a problem and I would like to you guys help me out.

When I swipe my UISlider, the music starts from beginning again and not from the new point.

```
-(IBAction)progressChange{
    if (!audioPlayer)
    {
        return;
    }

    [audioPlayer seekToTime:audioSlider.value];
}

#pragma -mark funcao timer
-(void)setupTimer
{
    timer = [NSTimer timerWithTimeInterval:0.25 target:self selector:@selector(tick) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

    [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] addTimer:timer forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
}

#pragma -mark funcao tick do timer
-(void)tick
{

    if (!audioPlayer || audioPlayer.duration == 0)
    {
        audioSlider.value = 0;

        return;
    }

    audioSlider.minimumValue = 0;
    audioSlider.maximumValue = audioPlayer.duration;
    audioSlider.value = audioPlayer.progress;
}
```

here is a piece of my code, hope you guys can help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This will happen if your web server is not capable of handling HTTP RANGE requests.